# echarts4r won't render in Quarto

Tags: r, quarto, echarts4r

I am having trouble rendering an echart for object.

I've checked the documentation and numerous tutorials but for some reason I can't render an echart4r chart in html quarto file -- Am I missing something?

I receive the below error when rendering in quarto -- Its not clear to me why

```
Quitting from lines 14-23 [unnamed-chunk-1] (test_echarts4r.qmd)
Error in add_html_caption():
! unused argument (xfun::grep_sub("^[^<]<[^>]+aria-labelledby[ ]=[ ]"([^\"]+)".$", "\1", x))
```

````
---
title: "echarts4r"
format: html
---

```{r}
library(echarts4r)
library(tidyverse)

diamonds %>% 
  count(color) %>% 
  echarts4r::e_charts(x = color) %>% 
  echarts4r::e_bar(serie = n)
```
````

I've created a issue in the repo:

https://github.com/JohnCoene/echarts4r/issues/554

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by updating Quarto to latest current release version